# letsencrypt works www but not root domain (apache)

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, telnet, lets-encrypt

i'm trying to install letsencrypt on a server, both www and the root domains are hosted by the box.  i can install with the www subdomain no problem, but not the root domain.  here's the error i'm getting

```
Failed authorization procedure. domain.com (tls-sni-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Failed to connect to host for DVSNI challenge
```

A little further investigation reveals that I can telnet to port 443 using the www subdomain, but not the root domain nor the IP address.  I speculate that a solution to the latter problem will fix the former problem.

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Answer (score 2):

This issue might be related to one or more of the following:

1) Let's Encrypt certificates are generated per domain (so separate for www and root). You can create a certificate for several domains (SAN), but if this is not required, I suggest you create a separate certificate for each. **You might have created the certificate for www and not for root.** This is not automatically available like in most CA.

2) The root domain must be in your Virtual Host also, identified by ServerName.

3) The DNS record must point to your Server.

You can also try to install using the following:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt /opt/letsencrypt
cd /opt/letsencrypt
./letsencrypt-auto --apache -d example.com
```

or

```
./letsencrypt-auto --apache -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

Comment: no luck, same error when attempting to create cert for plain domain.  any idea why i can telnet to www 443 but not domain 443?

Comment: Basic installation would start with a Non-SSL Virtual Host (port 80). Then you configure Let's Encrypt and it will give you the option to force HTTPS (then it will create a rewrite in your port 80 Virtual Host to redirect all traffic to HTTPS). Now if you don't set it to force HTTPS, it will not touch your port 80 Virtual Host and just create a new Virtual Host that's SSL Enabled. **Since you have not created your certificate yet, I assume the Virtual Host is not yet setup thus you can't connect telnet via 443**